# SQL Server Delete records greater than this time last year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012.  I need to delete data that is greater than this time last year.

So far example, delete any records greater than 28/11/**2015**.

This is rolling though and will be part of a SP that will run each day, so everyday it checks the current date and deletes.  What is the best way to do this?

```
DELETE tblmytable
where MyDateField > GETDATE ()
```

How do I change to say > Today from last year?

Comment: Do you mean *less than*?  Today is greater than this time last year.  Assume you are trying to delete old records?

Answer (score 5):

Use dateadd

```
DELETE 
from tblmytable
where MyDateField > dateadd(yy, -1, GETDATE ())
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, this is the answer:

```
Delete tblmytable
where MyDateField > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: while close, its syntax is incorrect, you are missing from after delete.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
delete from table
where dateField > dateadd(yy, -1, getdate())
```

Comment: This question already has same answer posted by another user. If you want to differentiate your answer, please add more detail.